# Separate each member of a union type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have a **generated** union type that looks something like:

```
type Result = { type: 'car' } | { type: 'boat' }
```

How can I separate them so that I can create an individual type for each of these? eg:

```
type BoatResult = { type: 'boat' }
type CarResult = { type: 'card' }
```

Where they have to be created from the original `Result` type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Extract` conditional type to `Extract` to get a type out of a union that extends a given type. If your union is actually as simple as in the question it does not make much sense, but if you have extra fields you can use this to extract the full type from the union.

```
type Result = { type: 'car', a: number } | { type: 'boat', b: string }

type Car = Extract<Result, { type: 'car' }> //{ type: 'car', a: number }
type Boat = Extract<Result, { type: 'boat'} > // { type: 'boat', b: string }
```